# Vlookup or Indexing using google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadshseet (Sheet1) in which the Data is there from Col A to Column D, and in another sheet (Sheet1), again the data is there from Col A to Col W, in which the Col F data has some matching with column D.

**What i am seeking for:**

I want to pull data from Sheet2 (from Col F onwards, i.e. G, H, I etc.) in Col E and so on in Sheet1.
**Sheet2**
Col

F G  H  I  J  K  L
1 A  B  C  D  E  F
2 a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1
3 a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2
and so on

**Sheet1**
Col D  E  F  G  H
    1  A  B  C  D
    3  a2 b2 c2 d2

Data to reflect in col E,F,G H in sheet1 from sheet2 against column D in col E,F, either using vlookup, or indexing.

**What i tried but in Vain**
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/HzeNdIqnIUc

I want to use only google apps only to get the desired results.

Requesting for help on this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you're having a problem with your VLOOKUP but it's a Google Spreadsheets user question not a stackoverflow (programming) question. It might help you to know these things:

1. You're on the right track with VLOOKUP. The spreadsheet function VLOOKUP definitely works for getting data in sheet2 to lookup based on keys/columns in sheet1. It works really well for what you say you need to do.
2. You can search the Google support site: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/search.py?query=vlookup
3. You can ask in the Google Docs Help forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old article but others may still stumble across it.

Here is something I wrote to address my Vlookup Needs in script form.

```
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
//--//Dependent on isEmpty_()
// Script Look-up
/*
Benefit of this script is:
-That google sheets will not continually do lookups on data that is not changing with using this function as it is set with hard values until script is kicked off again.
-Unlike Vlookup you can have it look at for reference data at any Column in the row.  Does not have to be in the first column for it to work like Vlookup.
-You can return the Lookup to Memory for further processing by other functions

Useage:

var LocNum    = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetID).getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('J2:J').getValues();

Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[1],"Sheet1!I1","n","y");
//or
Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[1],"return","n","n");
//or
Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",0,[0,1],"return","n","n");
//or
Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:B",1,[0],"return","y","n");
//or
Lookup_(Sheetinfo,"Sheet1!A:G",4,[0],"Database!A1","y","y");
*/



function Lookup_(Search_Key,RefSheetRange,SearchKey_Ref_IndexOffSet,IndexOffSetForReturn,SetSheetRange,ReturnMultiResults,Add_Note)   
{
  var RefSheetRange = RefSheetRange.split("!");
  var Ref_Sheet = RefSheetRange[0];
  var Ref_Range = RefSheetRange[1];

  if(!/return/i.test(SetSheetRange))
  {
  var SetSheetRange = SetSheetRange.split("!");
  var Set_Sheet = SetSheetRange[0];
  var Set_Range = SetSheetRange[1];
  var RowVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_Range).getRow();
  var ColVal = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_Range).getColumn();
  }

  var twoDimensionalArray = [];
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Ref_Sheet).getRange(Ref_Range).getValues();         //Syncs sheet by name and range into var
  for (var i = 0, Il=Search_Key.length; i<Il; i++)                                                         // i = number of rows to index and search  
  {
    var Sending = [];                                                                                      //Making a Blank Array
    var newArray = [];                                                                                     //Making a Blank Array
    var Found ="";
    for (var nn=0, NNL=data.length; nn<NNL; nn++)                                                                 //nn = will be the number of row that the data is found at
    {
      if(Found==1 && ReturnMultiResults.toUpperCase() == 'N')                                                                                         //if statement for found if found = 1 it will to stop all other logic in nn loop from running
      {
        break;                                                                                             //Breaking nn loop once found
      }
      if (data[nn][SearchKey_Ref_IndexOffSet]==Search_Key[i])                                              //if statement is triggered when the search_key is found.
      {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var cc=0, CCL=IndexOffSetForReturn.length; cc<CCL; cc++)                                         //cc = numbers of columns to referance
        {
          var iosr = IndexOffSetForReturn[cc];                                                             //Loading the value of current cc
          var Sending = data[nn][iosr];                                                                    //Loading data of Level nn offset by value of cc
          if(isEmpty_(Sending))                                                                      //if statement for if one of the returned Column level cells are blank
          {
          var Sending =  "#N/A";                                                                           //Sets #N/A on all column levels that are blank
          }
          if (CCL>1)                                                                                       //if statement for multi-Column returns
          {
            newArray.push(Sending);
            if(CCL-1 == cc)                                                                                //if statement for pulling all columns into larger array
            {
              twoDimensionalArray.push(newArray);
              var Found = 1;                                                                              //Modifying found to 1 if found to stop all other logic in nn loop
              break;                                                                                      //Breaking cc loop once found
            }
          }
          else if (CCL<=1)                                                                                 //if statement for single-Column returns
          {
            twoDimensionalArray.push(Sending);
            var Found = 1;                                                                                 //Modifying found to 1 if found to stop all other logic in nn loop
            break;                                                                                         //Breaking cc loop once found
          }
        }
      }
      if(NNL-1==nn && isEmpty_(Sending))                                                             //following if statement is for if the current item in lookup array is not found.  Nessessary for data structure.
      {
        for(var na=0,NAL=IndexOffSetForReturn.length;na<NAL;na++)                                          //looping for the number of columns to place "#N/A" in to preserve data structure
        {
          if (NAL<=1)                                                                                      //checks to see if it's a single column return
          {
            var Sending = "#N/A";
            twoDimensionalArray.push(Sending);
          }
          else if (NAL>1)                                                                                  //checks to see if it's a Multi column return
          {
            var Sending = "#N/A";
            newArray.push(Sending);
          }
        }
        if (NAL>1)                                                                                         //checks to see if it's a Multi column return
        {
          twoDimensionalArray.push(newArray);  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (CCL<=1)                                                                                            //checks to see if it's a single column return for running setValue
  {
    var singleArrayForm = [];
    for (var l = 0,lL=twoDimensionalArray.length; l<lL; l++)                                                          //Builds 2d Looping-Array to allow choosing of columns at a future point
    {
      singleArrayForm.push([twoDimensionalArray[l]]);
    }
    if(!/return/i.test(SetSheetRange))
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,singleArrayForm.length,singleArrayForm[0].length).setValues(singleArrayForm);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      if(/y/i.test(Add_Note))
      {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,1,1).setNote("VLookup Script Ran On: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a") + "\nRange: " + Ref_Sheet + "!" + Ref_Range);      
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return singleArrayForm
    }
  }
  if (CCL>1)                                                                                             //checks to see if it's a multi column return for running setValues
  {
    if(!/return/i.test(SetSheetRange))
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,twoDimensionalArray.length,twoDimensionalArray[0].length).setValues(twoDimensionalArray);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      if(/y/i.test(Add_Note))
      {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(RowVal,ColVal,1,1).setNote("VLookup Script Ran On: " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a") + "\nRange: " + Ref_Sheet + "!" + Ref_Range);      
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return twoDimensionalArray
    }
  }

}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
// Empty String Check
function isEmpty_(string) 
{
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(string) == '[object Boolean]') return false;

  if(!string)             return true;         
  if(string == '')        return true;
  if(string === false)    return true; 
  if(string === null)     return true; 
  if(string == undefined) return true;
  string = string+' '; // check for a bunch of whitespace
  if('' == (string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''))) return true;       

  return false;        
}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
```